# How to clear session of open error

Tags: sas

When working is the base sas client, if a user accidentially forgets a parathesis, quote, semi-colon, or end-comment that will sometimes cause any additional code they try running to fail.  If I'm trying to help someone experiencing one of these errors, how can I clear the current buffer and start fresh without opening a brand new session?

Comment: FYI - the way you worded this may get you close votes, as technically "what is the best way" is an opinion question (which is not valid on SO).  You might reword as something more like "how can I" to avoid those to some extent.

Comment: @Joe, Thanks, I've changed the question to try and remove subjectivity

Answer (score 2):

I've always used the one documented on support.sas.com 
http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001302436.htm

```
*'; *"; *); */; %mend; run;
```

Submit that until you get the log message :

```
ERROR: No matching %MACRO statement for this %MEND statement.
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no true best way, as it depends on too many things.  Presumably the user will know what might have gone wrong, and can use that information; for example, are we possibly missing a %mend somewhere that caused us to get locked into a macro?

The EG method is one of the better ones.  At the start of every EG process (ie, every time you hit 'Run' on a program or section of program), it runs:

```
;*';*";*/;quit;run;
```

That:

- Semicolon ends any statement that hadn't ended
- Comment singlequote, and comment doublequote, end any trailing quotes (both trailed by ; )
- Star slash ends any block comments
- Quit and run end any procedures that had been left open.

EG doesn't include `%mend;` because it would generate a warning, but you could include that if you didn't mind the warning and wanted to catch one of the common issues.  If you do include it, put it up front - macros will not properly deal with those hanging quotes, and you need to be out of them for sure first.